# Most efficient way to do Mysql Multi select (and insert if not exists)

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, lastinsertid

I have 20 tables with 2 fields, id and name description

```
Colors
id  name
1 black
2 blue 
...

Sizes
id name  
1 100
2 105
...
```

Now i have the main table with 21 fields

```
Main table `shoes`

id Colors Sizes style ...
1    2     24     11
```

I have a form post with  20 text inputs (one for each kind of feature, color, size..) 
 what i want is to learn the most efficient way to look at 20 features tables (Select id from colors where name='blue') and get the id value, if not exists, create it ( insert into colors (name) values (pink) ) and then get the id ,once I have the 20 values ​​will do the big insert into the main field

Answer (score 0):

Use the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know your way, but  mean this to do 20 differents sentences?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: i mean.. should i do 20 times $db->(insert.. on duplicate key) ? is this the most efficient way?